# magento locale date format in transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.9, locale

My shop local is `sl_SI` and my current date format in order confirmation email is: `19. februar 2016 16.32.25 CET`

What I want to achieve is, to make this date format like this: `19. februar 2016 16:32:25 CET`

In email template there is a default date call: `{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}`

I did try to change locale date&time format in `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/si.xml` like this:

```
<timeFormatLength type="full">
    <timeFormat>
        <pattern>a h:mm:ss zzzz</pattern>
    </timeFormat>
</timeFormatLength>
<timeFormatLength type="long">
    <timeFormat>
        <pattern>a h:mm:ss z</pattern>
    </timeFormat>
</timeFormatLength>
<timeFormatLength type="medium">
    <timeFormat>
        <pattern>a h:mm:ss</pattern>
    </timeFormat>
</timeFormatLength>
<timeFormatLength type="short">
    <timeFormat>
        <pattern>a h:mm</pattern>
    </timeFormat>
</timeFormatLength>
```

but without success. If I change the locale in magento admin to `it_IT`, I can get desired date&time format. If I replace the `si.xml` file with `it.xml` content, it won't work. Like something is overriding my `si.xml` date format. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I noticed that I have edited wrong file. `si.xml` instead of `sl.xml`